# I want space between text paragraphs, but not list items

Tags: google-docs

I want a blank line between my text paragraphs but not between items in lists.

I know I can do the former with `Format > Line spacing > Add space after paragraph` and then `Update normal text to match`

That also adds space after each list item in my document's lists. I know I can fix each one individually with `Format > Line spacing > Remove space after list item`.

I would like to set it so that every text paragraph has space after, while every list item does not.

How can I do that?

Comment: @vicsar please read the question carefully before answering.  Your answer simply reiterated the information in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately in the scenario you described, you do need to manually restore the paragraph spacing for any pre-existing lists.  Any new lists you create will not suffer the same issue.

The way you are resolving it, `Format > Line spacing > Remove space after list item` does the job however it is very time-consuming, especially if there are multiple lists affected.

The good news is that the same result can be achieved with less effort by toggling the lists 'off' and then 'on'.

**Example** *(numbered list)***:**

1. Select/highlight the list items
2. Click the `Numbered list` button [image] to convert it to paragraph text.
3. Click the button [image] again to restore it to a `Numbered list`

**Keyboard shortcuts** can be used instead of the menu buttons

| Type | Keyboard Shortcut |
| --- | --- |
| Numbered list | <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> |
| Bulleted list | <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> |
| Checklist | <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> |

<sub>**Restoring List Formating after Style Change**</sub>
<kbd>[image]</kbd>